# How to extract the user cell information from received message?

Tags: geolocation

i am about to develop a location based service for simple mobile (a mobile have no GPS,or wifi) through sms. so to know the location of my user i want to know with which cell Id are they communicating. Therefore how can i extract their cell information from the message i received from them?

Answer (score 0):

The SMS message does no contain any infomration of the sender's location, thus there is no ways you could extract that information from the received SMS message.

Anyway's there are Cellbased positioning APIs available on a device, so check the platform you are developing for, and see what APIs there are offered.

And then of course you can have the location sent over SMS to receiving end, but indeed it would mean that you have your application running in both ends.

In general Phone operators can offer location based services, in which they could locate devices which are using their network, but in general they usually don't let normal developer to access that kind of infomration.

Comment: If using SMS message is not possible i can change to USSD(Unstructured Supplementary Services Data) message to make interactive communication between the user and my application, but what i am not sure is, In ussd application, is it possible to allow the user to send text? for example if i asked them where are you? just their village or local name?  because i already have their village geolocation.